# How to pack my Python Project with the third party modules to run as a single Application on a Windows Platform

Tags: python

I am doing a project in Python Language. I have used a large number of third party modules to add more functionality to the project. All are for the Python 3.3. My question how can I package my whole project into a single Application with all the third party modules to run on Windows platform.

I searched for the same but only answer I found was that you have to manually copy all the required modules with you project. But not only want to include the party modules but also to pack the whole thing in a exe file.

Comment: combine in a single file (exe)

Comment: Can pyinstaller py2exe combine third party modules?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian pyinstaller does not support Python3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [pynsist](http://pynsist.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), it does almost precisely what you ask for.

It works by creating an MSI installer with the Python core distribution, your module and your dependencies. This MSI will then install a Start-Menu shortcut that allows you to launch your application.

For example (this is verbatim from the documentation):

Create a file `installer.cfg`:

```
[Application]
name=My App
version=1.0
# How to launch the app - this calls the 'main' function from the 'myapp' package:
entry_point=myapp:main
icon=myapp.ico

[Python]
version=3.4.0

[Include]
# Importable packages that your application requires, one per line
packages = requests
     bs4
     html5lib

# Other files and folders that should be installed
files = LICENSE
    data_files/
```

Make sure you have `pip install`ed `pynsist` and run:

```
$ pynsist installer.cfg
```

You can then find the created MSI installers under `build/nsis`

There are some disadvantages, though:

- The application is not a single *exe file, but a whole directory and a startmenu shortcut
- The Python interpreter will be installed system-wide
- The MSI is rather large

Comment: Finally Something Useful. Its not entirely what I wanted but its a start. Thank You

Comment: For completeness, we should also mention [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/), which does produce an exe, albeit one that depends on a bunch of extra files. Pynsist is my new project, though, so I'm keen to see people trying it out. ;-)